# What's the problem with RapidApi not seeing the key header?

Tags: node.js, angular, api, axios, translation

So I have this method in my Angular Node.js app:

```
async translateWord(word: string) {
const key = '*I put it here*';

const translation = await axios({
  "method": "POST",
  "url": "https://google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com/language/translate/v2",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/octet-stream",
    "x-rapidapi-host": "google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key": key,
    "useQueryString":true
  },
  "data": {
    "source": "en",
    "q": word,
    "target": "ru"
  }
});

console.log(translation.data);
}
```

The result of calling the method is

> POST https://google-translate1.p.rapidapi.com/language/translate/v2 502 (Bad Gateway)

When I right-click on the failed request in Chrome dev tools window and open it in new tab, I get the following message:

> {"message":"Missing RapidAPI application key. Go to https://docs.rapidapi.com/docs/keys to learn how to get your API application key."}

The weird thing is that I actually have the key in my headers: [proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgP6I.png)

Also I get the correct translation when I execute the same code snippet via RapidApi interface.

Comment: Looking at the docs, header `content-type` seem to contain value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and the header ` "accept-encoding":"application/gzip"` is missing from your request. Could you please try again with them?

Comment: @MichaelD Thanks for your answer. I changed it, but still having the same errors + the new one: Refused to set unsafe header "accept-encoding".

Comment: Then I am not exactly sure.

Comment: @MichaelD ok tnx for your help anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RapidAPI supports passing the API key via a query parameter. You can do this by including the following syntax in the link:

```
https://example.p.rapidapi.com/?rapidapi-key=***************************
```

However, please keep in mind that your RapidAPI key is used across your entire account. Be careful about exposing your key if the link is publicly accessible.